# log4j2 -- Today's log files are going to stored in old log files

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

After running the server today, my today log files are going to stored in yesterday log files.
what is the solution for this issue?

Comment: Did you configure any rolling file appender based on date (not size)? If not, then look it up and configure that. This might already solve your problem.

Comment: Can you please add your log4j2.xml file to your original question. Then I can have a look at it and diagnose your logging problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.